# Incorrect syntax on user defined scalar function with case expression

Tags: sql-server, case, user-defined-functions

I've tried a few variations and I can't get this syntax correct:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ComputeNextDate] 
( 
    @pInputDate    DATETIME 
    , @Interval    VARCHAR(20)

)
RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN

DECLARE @vOutputDate        DATETIME

SELECT 
    CASE @vOutputDate 
        When @Interval = 'Weekly' Then DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @pInputDate)
        When @Interval = 'Yearly' Then DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @pInputDate)
END


RETURN @vOutputDate

END
```

This is what the parser returns and I am confused:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ComputeNextDate, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ComputeNextDate, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the two different syntaxes of the `case` expression, use one or the other. Also you need an assignment in the `select` to get the value into the variable:

```
SELECT
  @vOutputDate =
    CASE
        When @Interval = 'Weekly' Then DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @pInputDate)
        When @Interval = 'Yearly' Then DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @pInputDate)
END
```

or:

```
SELECT 
  @vOutputDate =
    CASE @Interval
        When 'Weekly' Then DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @pInputDate)
        When 'Yearly' Then DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @pInputDate)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the previous answer you can set your output variable while using the case without a select statement, something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ComputeNextDate] 
    ( 
        @pInputDate    DATETIME 
        , @Interval    VARCHAR(20)

    )
    RETURNS DATETIME
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @vOutputDate        DATETIME

    SET @vOutputDate = CASE  
                        When @Interval = 'Weekly' Then DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @pInputDate)
                        When @Interval = 'Yearly' Then DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @pInputDate)
                   END


    RETURN @vOutputDate

END
```